# LogMeIn.com and interference on certain websites

Tags: website, virus, logmein

I'm using [LogMeIn.com](http://www.logmein.com) to provide over-the-internet computer support to my father-in-law.

During the time I install it, the computer had a virus. I was trying to quickly rid the computer of the virus without having to drive over to his house. I'm using [AVG Anti-Virus Free edition](http://free.avg.com/download?prd=afe) as his virus scanner. It has always worked for me in the past. The virus has been removed (according to AVG).

The point of this post is that since I've installed [LogMeIn.com](http://www.logmein.com), he is having trouble accessing certain websites. For one a banking website and two a product purchase website to buy something.

I'm getting unclear reports on what happens when these sites are visited but basically "they don't work".

I need to find out if this is an artifact of the virus or if this is due to LogMeIn.com. I like LogMeIn and I'd like to continue to use it but if this probably is caused by this software, I'll remove the software....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used Logmein extensively to support family, and have never seen any problems with it interfering with browsing.  You are probably going to want to dig deeper into network, dns, Internet Explorer, or user problems.

Starting points
check the hosts file. (viruses will sometimes edit these to redirect where they want.)
check the dns settings
check the IE default search settings. (hijackthis makes this easier)
And, continue to check for viruses and spyware.

Comment: On your advice, I think I identified the problem as a program called "Personal Virus Scanner" that my father-in-law installed to try to get rid of the virus him self. Apparently, it is malware. http://www.geekpolice.net/offending-urls-f41/suspicious-domain-blockcom-t11778.htm  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the free [CrossLoop](http://www.crossloop.com) service.  It's a very good, free service.

Comment: FYI for visitors, CrossLoop was retired.